find -printf for file creation time is not working as expected, is it a bug?
I'm trying to print file date of birth ( crtime ), I'm working with ext4 and support for crtime enable:
stat a
  File: a
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 254,5   Inode: 393233      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1006/    user)   Gid: ( 1006/    user)
Access: 2024-06-24 13:35:25.672343713 +0200
Modify: 2024-06-24 13:35:25.672343713 +0200
Change: 2024-06-24 13:35:25.672343713 +0200
 Birth: 2024-06-24 13:35:25.672343713 +0200

when trying to display date of birt with find -printf '%B@' as the manual indicate :
%Bk    File's  birth  time,  i.e., its creation time, in the format 
specified by k, which is the same as for %A. 
This directive produces an empty string if the underlying operating 
system  or  filesystem does not support birth times.

I get that result :
find -name a -printf '%B@ %p\n' 
-1.-000000010 ./a

Is it a bug or is it a feature I don't know about or something else.
I'm using find version 4.9.0-5 (and tested version -4 as well).
I've tried on Ubuntu and Debian.

Not 100% sure if this was the latest thread on the subject - but I guess its not supported in GNU find as per https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61327#comment4

Can also be seen in the 4.9 changelog https://savannah.gnu.org/news/?id=10072

You can use https://github.com/tavianator/bfs which is drop-in compatible with GNU find and supports -printf %B on Linux

@TavianBarnes Thank you for the tips, I like the idea of the tool

This is a known bug: Linux exposes the creation time via the new statx system call whereas GNU find uses the traditional stat/lstat. Other GNU utilities have made the switch but not find.

I'm not crazy then.
Thank you for the clear explanation.

Not really a bug, it's just it's not implemented yet for Linux-based operating systems.

@StéphaneChazelas with how is written the manual I'd argue it is a bug on a user perspective :-D
